# Unable to indentify the element in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am automating one of the commercial application and when I try to identify element using CSS,Xpath, ID, the element is being identified and shows as only one  matching node in Firebug, but when I use that element for the test case automation.I see the below error

**An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code**

Please find the below html code for the application

```
<div id="QueryOption1" class="SelectedDiv" xmlns:local="#local-functions" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" name="QueryOptions">
<span>
<div>
<div class="leftSide">Subscriber ID:       </div>
<input id="Subscriber_ID" class="floatLeft" type="text" name="InsuranceNum" size="15"/>
</div>
```

Below is the options that I have tried

By.id("Subscriber_First_Name")

By.CssSelector("#QueryOption1 > div > #Subscriber_Last_Name")

By.Xpath("//input[@id='Subscriber_First_Name']")

By.CssSelector("input[id=Subscriber_First_Name][type=text]")

None of them worked for me to pass the value into the text box.PLease kindly help

Comment: Can you please share the complete code you use to interact with the element?

Comment: driver.FindElement(ObtainEntities.Subscriber_First_Name).SendKeys("Fred");

Answer (score 0):

why are you using id as :- Subscriber_First_Name while in your above HTML "id" is:-

```
By.id("QueryOption1")   // for first div
By.id("Subscriber_ID")   //for input tag

By.xpath("//input[@id='Subscriber_ID']")
```

OR you can use name locator also

```
By.name("QueryOptions")
By.name("InsuranceNum")
```

OR can set the value using JavascriptExecutor

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
jse.executeScript("$('#Subscriber_ID').attr('value','user')");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get it using IJavaScriptExecuter

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor jsExc = browser as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string textValue = jsExc.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('Subscriber_ID').value;").ToString();
```

Comment: I am sorry please find the HTML code

<div id="QueryOption1" class="SelectedDiv" xmlns:local="#local-functions" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" name="QueryOptions">
<span>
<div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
<div>
<div class="leftSide">Subscriber First Name: </div>
<input id="Subscriber_First_Name" class="floatLeft" type="text" name="InsuredFirstName" size="15">

Comment: There's no reason to use `IJavaScriptExecutor`. You should be able to use "normal" methods to get the element.

Comment: I tried with the all the element locators and it is not working.Can you please share me the exact IJavaScriptExecutor code to pass the value on the webElement(Subscriber First Name) in the UI

Comment: IJavaScriptExecutor jsExc = browserVariable as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string textValue = jsExc.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('Subscriber_First_Name').value;").ToString();

this is how you can get it. btw = you have to change browserVariable with your browser variable name

Comment: I added the code but still it didnt worked. IJavaScriptExecutor jsExc = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
         string textValue = jsExc.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('Subscriber_First_Name').value;").ToString();

Comment: it maybe not working because you have more than one element with that id

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why the HTML you provided shows the id for the INPUT as Subscriber_ID and you are using Subscriber_First_Name in your code examples. That could be the issue but you didn't provide the actual code you are using so I'm not sure.

Try this

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Subscriber_ID")).SendKeys("some text goes into the text box");
```